# What's wrong with this linear program formulation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

> You have two item factories, $A$ and $B$, and there are two clients
>   that buy such item.
>
> Each client has a demand - the first one needs $400$, and the second
>   $300$.
>
> Each factory has a storage of items - $A$ has $a$ and $B$ has $b$.
>
> There is a transportation cost per item from one factory to a client.
>   For the first factory, it costs $30$ for the first client, and $25$
>   for the second. For the second factory, it would be $36$ and $30$.
>
> You want to supply the clients with the minimum transportation cost.

---

Well then,

[image]

> Formulate a linear program for this. Assume that the factories are
>   allowed to have leftover supplies.

Ok, for starters, surely $x_1+x_3 = 400$ and $x_2+x_4 = 300$?

$$\begin{cases}
x_1+x_3 = 400\\
x_2+x_4 = 300
\end{cases}$$

Next, the factories shouldn't be able to supply more than their storage, so...

$$\begin{cases}
x_1+x_3 = 400\\
x_2+x_4 = 300\\
x_1+x_2 \le a\\
x_3+x_4 \le b
\end{cases}$$

So the objective function would be like

$$\min z = 30x_1 + 25x_2 + 36x_3 + 30x_4$$

I'm not sure if the above formulation is correct, but it looks fine so let's try to solve the program:

---

Transform the inequalities...

$$\begin{cases}
x_1+x_3 = 400\\
x_2+x_4 = 300\\
x_1+x_2 + x_5 = a\\
x_3+x_4 + x_6 = b
\end{cases}$$

The matrix looks like...

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 400 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 300 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & b \\
30 & 25 & 36 & 30 & 0 & 0 & z
\end{bmatrix}$$

<s>Wait. There's nothing to do here. The objective row has no negative terms, so the Simplex algorithm ends. This only suggests me that something did not go well - what was it?</s>

I was told to create two artificial variables, so here goes:

---

The third and fourth column are not canonical, so we will add two artificial variables, $\color{red}{x_7, x_8}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}1 & 0 & 400 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}1 & 300 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
30 & 25 & 36 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & z
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have expanded the program, so now we must solve

$$\min w = x_7 + x_8$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 400 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 300 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
30 & 25 & 36 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & w
\end{bmatrix}$$

We must make the seventh and fourth columns canonical, by getting rid of the $1$s at the last row. This is done with

$$-r_1 + r_6 , -r_2 + r_6$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 400 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 300 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
30 & 25 & 36 & 30 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & z \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & w - 700
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we must solve this expanded program with the Simplex method. However, I can't find the pivot because $a / 1 = a$ and I don't know what $a$ is...

Comment: You've asked for this question to be deleted, but that would shortchange the effort of Brian. We prefer not to delete upvoted content. What I would recommend is that you edit your question with your realization (or write another answer, doesn't really matter), and accept Brian's answer (or your answer - whatever actually fits more). By the way, it's a very nicely written question, even if it doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 2):

What are your basic variables?  You need to solve for them in the tableau to get a BFS.

Comment: Oooh, I see - so I need to add two artificial variables, since I already have other two, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to do some kind of phase I procedure to get a BFS.

Comment: I have added the variables and progressed on the problem. Now I have to solve an expanded program, but I can't find the pivot because $a$ is on the righthand side and I don't know the value of $a$. Does that mean I should have moved $a$ to the lefthand from the beginning?